# How to guess module name

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I've seen this kind of check in several .htaccess files. The code below is from Wordpress:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /wordpress/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /wordpress/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

I understand what `<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>` check is, but I don't know where is this name coming from. I'm assuming that `mod_rewrite.c` is the source-code filename of that module.

**How can one make a `<IfModule mod_something.c>` check and insert the correct module name?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out how the modules are named and how I can check for a different module if it's active or not.

A list of all Apache modules can be found [here](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/).
By clicking any module link, it will load a page where `Source File:` field is displayed.

So, if I want to check if [mod_remoteip](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_remoteip.html) is enabled, I would check it like this:

```
<IfModule mod_remoteip.c>
# my code
</IfModule>
```